# After adding snippit of code to default/setting.php bombarded by header warnings

Tags: drupal-7, runtime, duplicates, warnings, heading

I'm quite aware this question has been asked before multiple times, but I have no idea how to deal with this in my specfic situation. All I did was modify the default/settings.php file in order for the toolbar drawer in drupal to support more shortcuts.

I inserted the following code in the bottom of the document:

```
 /**
 * Changing Max Shortcut Slots
 *
 * The shortcut module supports a total of seven shortcuts slots. To change 
 * the quantity of supported enabled shortcuts the 'shortcut_max_slots' must be
 * modified accordingly.
 *
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/shortcut
 */
$conf['shortcut_max_slots'] = 11;
```

Well I got it to work, which is good, but I'm assaulted by a barrage of warnings, each one stating the following:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/adamdcco/public_html/hadarc.com/cms/sites/default/settings.php:1) in drupal_send_headers() (line 1221 of /home/adamdcco/public_html/hadarc.com/cms/includes/bootstrap.inc).

I'm lost, I looked into the bootstrap file and navigated to the specficed line and, unfortunately no lightbulb. Sorry I'm new :), but I did search around, before being utterly overwhelmed
Any and all help is appreciated :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well than looks like we're good :)

I searched around some more and came across this question/answer
[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) , in a nutshell it's the same question, amazing answer, so yeah just in case anyone cared the code I inputted:

```
$conf['shortcut_max_slots'] = 11;
```

should of had quotes around the eleven, and any extra spaces in the beginning and in the end of the file had to be removed. Live and Learn :)